# Windows 7 PATH environment variable expansion

Tags: windows, variables, path, environment, expansion

In Windows 7 I set the PATH environment variable thus:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;R:\bin;P:\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intuit\QBPOSSDKRuntime;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
```

When I log out and log in, and then bring up a command prompt, all my environment variables are properly expanded---except M2_HOME. If I bring up the edit window for the PATH environment variable and simply hit OK with no edits, when I open up a command prompt the M2_HOME variable is properly replaced, and remains so until I log out.

I don't understand this. Even if this were a definition order problem, M2_HOME appears before PATH alphabetically. What's going on?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but are you talking about the system variable PATH or the user variable PATH ?  Is M2_HOME a system variable or a user variable ? System environment variables should not contain references to user environment variables, so that might possibly be the problem.

Comment: These were all system variables. I'm not sure if the problem is still occurring---it could have been some odd thing Microsoft fixed with an update.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a solution, I hope this will help you track down your issue.  I have recently faced various issues with Windows 7 and Path expansion.  Try removing the entries you have with spaces, if that does not help, remove everything except the stock entries and M2_HOME.  I am just recommending you to remove this to see if it helps you track down your issue.  If you determine that an entry with a space is causing this, we can look for another solution (8.3 path?)...

Comment: removing entries and re-adding worked for me ... must be some windows bug

Answer (score 1):

I have Windows 7 and use maven, so I have M2_HOME and M2 environment variables and they work OK.  If you want to see what's going on inside you can use the [RapidEE](http://www.RapidEE.com) environment variable editor.  That may help.

- [www.RapidEE.com](http://www.RapidEE.com)

I can show you what I have:

- M2      = %M2_HOME%\bin
- M2_HOME = b:\repository\maven\v03.00
- path    = ...;%M2%; ...

Seems to work OK.  I didn't do much checking on expansions because everything was working.

If I look at path in the shell, is expands to

- path    = ...;b:\repository\maven\v03.00\bin; ...

Good luck, w.